# Ms Access dropbox options depending on category?

Tags: database, ms-access, relational-database

I'm making a database for class, and in it, I have race categories which certain age groups can compete in.

I need to be able to choose, for example, "age 20+", and then have the races they can compete in show up as options - be it in the form of a Dropbox or otherwise.

I'll need another age group, say "age 30+" when clicked to show different race options.

I have tried boolean but I can only get these options to show up in a single string list, so no individual option can be chosen.

Ideas?

Comment: You need to include sample data and an example of what you have tried. Actual data rather than a picture is much preferred.

Comment: Have your mimum age set in a column where your race categoriea are.    The dropbox should just be a number or remember to remove the "+" when using in your WHERE statement.  I.e. MinAge > AgeChooser